# Is it Possible to Add a Button/Link to Move Site?

Tags: site, architecture, design

I'm new to SharePoint 2010 administration and I'm trying to set up a project site archive system where my users can simply click a button/link either in the ribbon or on the home page of the project site somewhere, and cause the page to be relocated over to a blank site I've setup to hold old projects. Is this possible?

I was thinking it could possibly be done with workflows being triggered by a link or something, but I wasn't able to find any information on actually moving sites with workflows, only libraries/lists.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Just complex... the way I would tackle this (and there may be a better way) is to create a simple web part with one button. In the click event of the button I would use a mixture of C# (to create the new web and where ever possible) and to call code to run PowerShell stsadm commands to achieve this...

For the PowerShell commands see:

http://www.themackpage.com/2009/05/14/how-to-move-a-sharepoint-site/

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=205

To invoke PowerShell from C# see:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments

After you've made this web part (and thoroughly tested of course) I'd incorporate it into your master page.

Last words of advice: remember to check if it's a site collection or a web as the process varies, and make sure you disable it at the web application scope!

Like I said: possible, just complex.